# Use the answer of a prompt to swap placeholders in another file

Tags: bash, sed

I have a file named file.txt with filled with many words "placeholder"

I want to use the answer to the following to dictate what "placeholder" is replaced with:

```
#!/bin/bash
while [ "$response" != "n" ]
do
read -p "What is the answer? " $answer
sed -i 's/placeholder/$answer/g' file.txt
  exit
done
```

However this is not working, as use of the ' with `sed` no longer references the answer above.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

EDIT: 
Thank you to @RavinderSingh13 below, for your help. I also deleted the $ before the answer but left it in the `sed` command and it all worked out. 
Final Script:

```
#!/bin/bash
while [ "$response" != "n" ]
do
read -p "What is the answer? " answer
sed -i "s/placeholder/$answer/g" file.txt
  exit
done
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could you please try changing `sed -i 's/placeholder/$answer/g' file.txt` to:

```
sed -i "s/placeholder/$answer/g" file.txt
```

Since `"` gives opportunity to expand variable's value where `'` takes `$` as literal character, also couldn't test complete code since no samples were shown.

Also try changing `$always` in `read` command to `always`.

Comment: I had originally tried this, and it erases all of the instances of placeholder without replacing them with anything

Comment: Are you sure you have used `"` because I tested with a simple code and it worked for me.

Comment: Thank you, it worked I just had to change the "$answer" to "answer" in the read command, thank you so much!